# setInterval() called twice at an interval [React js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAn7K.jpg)

Please look at the time printed on the console.

setInterval() looks like being called twice in on interval.

I attached my code below. I'd really appreciate it if you could give me a clue to the solution.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AppRouter from './Router';
import {authService} from '../fbase';

function App() {
  console.log('App()');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(authService.currentUser);
  console.log(authService.currentUser);
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log(Date().toLocaleString());
    console.log('In App.js > App()');
    console.log(authService.currentUser);
  }, 5000);
  return <AppRouter isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}></AppRouter>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should move calls like that into a useEffect function.

Comment: If you want `setInterval` to be called only once, you can convert `App` to a class based component, & call `setInterval` inside the `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: @NiceBooks Or keep using hooks and call it inside a useEffect with an empty dependency array.

Comment: The reason is most likely <StrictMode> wrapping your <App> in index.js, see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Answer (score 5):

Every time a state/prop changes your component will re-render. This means that everything that is not wrapped in a hook of some kind will also re-run. I'm not sure why this happens to you, maybe `authService.currentUser` returns two different values, an initial (probably empty) one when mounting the component and the correct one after it does some calculations (maybe you request the `user` from the back-end and it takes a while to get back the response -- some more code would be helpful here).

When the actual (correct) value will be returned from the `authService` to your function component it will re-render thus running `setInterval` again.

In order to make sure this never happens it's best to wrap our functionalities in a hook. If you want to run the `setInterval` just ONCE (when mounting the component) we can wrap it in an `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    ...
  }, 5000)
), []}
```

This means the hook will only run when your component first mounts.

If you need to run it based on some prop change (like when `isLoggedIn` changes from `false` to `true` or viceversa) you can add that to the dependency array and your interval will run every time `isLoggedIn` state changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    ...
  }, 5000)
}, [ isLoggedIn ])
```

If you only need to run that when `isLoggedIn` changes from `false` to `true` you can also add an `if` condition in your `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    setInterval(() => {
      ...
    }, 5000)
  }
}, [ isLoggedIn ])
```

More than that, as **Jose Antonio Castro Castro** mentioned, in all of the above cases you need to use a cleanup function in order to stop the interval from running indefinitely when your component unmounts (because it has no way of knowing to stop by itself). This is achieved by returning a function from your effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    ...
  }, 5000)

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
), []}
```

Don't forget that every time your component feels like re-rendering, all of your constants and functions that are called directly at the root of your component will be re-declared / re-run again.

The `useEffect`, `useCallback`, `useMemo` hooks help us with exactly that, but in different ways. Choose and use them wisely!

Comment: Thank u so much i will study harder

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, you need to call `setInterval` when you mount the component, but you need to stop the timer when it is unmounted.

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(function appRunTimer() {
    // Creates a new timer when mount the component.
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(Date().toLocaleString())
      console.log('In App.js > App()')
    }, 5000)
    
    // Stops the old timer when umount the component.
    return function stopTimer() {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])
  
  console.log('DRAW')
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1)}}>
      Click to update component's state: You click me {count} time(s)
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```